# Array of instances in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to create an array with 3 Hero instances.Then to define a function that returns a boolean if the level is more than 10 for all instances.(the instances sould inherit it). Then using a single cross to console.log the instances with the level more than 10. 
That's what I did. Can anyone give me a suggestion?

```js
    function Hero(name, level) {
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
    }

    var heroes = [
        new hero('Lucia', 4),
        new hero('Roxi', 33),
        new hero('Maria', 11),
    ];

    function getName() {
        for (var i = 0; i <= heroes.length; i++) {
            if (heroes[i].level > 10) {
                console.log(heroes[i].name);
            }
        }
    };

    getName();
```

Comment: `Hero` is not `hero`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> define a function that return an boolean if the level is more than 10 for all instances.(the instances should inherit it)

For using inheritance, you have to define the method on the Hero's prototype, then you can access the properties of a hero via `this`:

```
Hero.prototype.isReal = function() {
  console.log(this.level);
  return true /* or false */;
};
```

Now you can easily call that in your loop, for which I would also use the `for..of` syntax as its way easier to read:

```
const heroes = [ // Use const instead of var as often as possible
  new Hero('Lucia', 4), // must be *H*ero here
  new Hero('Roxi', 33),
  new Hero('Maria', 11) // and no comma at the end
];

for(const hero of heroes) { // thats way more readable
  if(hero.isReal()) { // Now you can use the inherited method
    console.log(hero.name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 errors in your code.

1. Change function name `Hero` to `hero`.
2. Loop should be till `less than` **(remove `=`)** `for (var i = 0; i < heroes.length; i++) {`

**Here is the simple javascript way you was trying:**

```js
function hero(name, level) {
this.name = name;
this.level = level;
}
var heroes = [
new hero('Lucia', 4),
new hero('Roxi', 33),
new hero('Maria', 11),
];
function getName() {
for (var i = 0; i < heroes.length; i++) {
    if (heroes[i].level > 10) {
        console.log(heroes[i].name);
    }
}
};
getName();
```